# Python Unittest mocking a function with an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, monkeypatching

I am trying to mock a function that has an argument that calls another method.

I recognize to patch a function without an argument you do this

```
def monthly_schedule(self, month):
        response = requests.get(f'http://company.com/{self.last}/{month}')
        if response.ok:
            return response.text
        else:
            return 'Bad Response!'
```

```
def test_monthly_schedule(self):
        with patch('employee.requests.get') as mocked_get:
            mocked_get.return_value.ok = True
            mocked_get.return_value.text = 'Success'

            schedule = self.emp_1.monthly_schedule('May')
            mocked_get.assert_called_with('http://company.com/Schafer/May')
            self.assertEqual(schedule, 'Success')
```

How would one mock a function that has the sort of syntax shown below?

Stock(ticker) is imported and is different than the 'Stocks' class.

```
from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
class Stocks:
    def price(self, ticker):
        price = Stock(ticker).get_price()
        self.myStockData.at["price", ticker] = price
```

A test with this sort of nature seems to throw a 'ModuleNotFoundError' on every variation of

```
with patch('stocks.Stock(ticker).get_price') as mock:
with patch('Stock(ticker).get_price') as mock:
with patch('stocks.get_price') as mock:
```

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from stocks import Stocks

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_price(self):
        with patch('stocks.Stock(ticker).get_price') as mock:
            mock = 300.00
            self.test.price('AAPL')
            self.assertEqual(self.test.myStockData.at["price", 'AAPL'], 300)
```

For brevity, not all code is shown. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Stock(ticker)` will return an object of some class, let's assume the class is `A`.  Then, the call `Stock(ticker).get_price` will call method `A.get_price`.  This is what you have to patch.